# What is the meaning of the GridSearchCV best_score_ attribute? (the value is different from the mean of the cross validation array)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm confused with the results, probably I'm not getting the concept of cross validation and GridSearch right. I had followed the logic behind this post: 
https://randomforests.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/basics-of-k-fold-cross-validation-and-gridsearchcv-in-scikit-learn/

```
argd = CommandLineParser(argv)
folder,fname=argd['dir'],argd['fname']

df = pd.read_csv('../../'+folder+'/Results/'+fname, sep=";")

explanatory_variable_columns = set(df.columns.values)
response_variable_column = df['A']
explanatory_variable_columns.remove('A')
y = np.array([1 if e else 0 for e in response_variable_column])

X =df[list(explanatory_variable_columns)].as_matrix()

kf_total = KFold(len(X), n_folds=5, indices=True, shuffle=True, random_state=4)

dt=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')

min_samples_split_range=[x for x in range(1,20)]
dtgs=GridSearchCV(estimator=dt, param_grid=dict(min_samples_split=min_samples_split_range), n_jobs=1)

scores=[dtgs.fit(X[train],y[train]).score(X[test],y[test]) for train, test in kf_total]
# SAME AS DOING: cross_validation.cross_val_score(dtgs, X, y, cv=kf_total, n_jobs = 1)

print scores
print np.mean(scores)
print dtgs.best_score_
```

## RESULTS OBTAINED:

```
# score [0.81818181818181823, 0.78181818181818186, 0.7592592592592593, 0.7592592592592593, 0.72222222222222221]
# mean score 0.768
# .best_score_ 0.683486238532
```

## ADDITIONAL NOTE:

I ran it using another combination of the explanatory variables (using only some of them) and I got the inverse problem. Now the .best_score_ is higher than all the values in the cross validation array.

```
# score [0.74545454545454548, 0.70909090909090911, 0.79629629629629628, 0.7407407407407407, 0.64814814814814814]
# mean score 0.728
# .best_score_ 0.802752293578
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is confusing several things.
`dtgs.fit(X[train_],y[train_])` does internal 3-fold cross-validation for every parameter combination from `param_grid`, producing a grid of 20 results, which you can open by calling `dtgs.grid_scores_`.

`[dtgs.fit(X[train_],y[train_]).score(X[test],y[test]) for train_, test in kf_total]` Therefore this line fits grid search five times and then takes its score using 5-Fold cross validation. The result is the array of scores of 5-Fold validation.

And when you call `dtgs.best_score_` you get the best score in the grid of the results of 3-fold validation of hyperparameters for the **last** fit (of 5).

Comment: Thank you. After posting the question I realized that Grid SearchCV does a cross validation of 3 folds by default. So my question is, I saw several blogs that they use GridSearchCV and then cross validation. So if cv is implicitly done in GridSearchCV why do then a cross_val_score??

Comment: There are numerous discussions of "why do then a cross_val score?" in CrossValidated.  This is one of the more detailed [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection)